# Updating multiple XML columns using single update in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I would like to update a `table_A` with new values for (AcresDist1, txtAcresDist1, txtAcresDist1Total) XML columns from a second `table_B`.

The column `P_XML` is of `XML` type. I know how to update a single column at once, but I would like to know how to update multiple columns in the XML using a single update statement. Thanks

SQL code:

```
UPDATE S
SET
   P_XML.modify( N'replace value of (/FormValue/f1152_F1/Field[(id/text())[1]="AcresDist1"]/value/text())[1] with sql:column(''T.AcresDist1'')' )
 , P_XML.modify( N'replace value of (/FormValue/f1152_F1/Field[(id/text())[1]="txtAcresDist1"]/value/text())[1] with sql:column(''T.txtAcresDist'')' )
 , P_XML.modify( N'replace value of (/FormValue/f1152_F1/Field[(id/text())[1]="txtAcresDist1Total"]/value/text())[1] with sql:column(''T.txtAcresDist1Total'')' )
FROM   
    Table_A AS S
INNER JOIN 
    Table_B AS T ON s.P_NO = t.P_Number
                 AND s.FAC_RID = t.Fac_RID;
```

Here is the sample xml as requested. Thank you.

```
<FormValue>
  <f1152>
<field>
  <id>f1152_MainForm</id>
  <value />
  <tag />
  <visible>true</visible>
  <history>|09/28/2017 10:50:26 AM||</history>
  <description />
  <comment />
</field>
<field>
  <id>txt_rdoCoverage</id>
  <value>Development</value>
  <tag />
  <visible>false</visible>
  <history>|09/28/2017 10:50:26 AM||</history>
  <description />
  <comment />
</field>
</f1152>
<f1152_F1>
<field>
 <id>txtAcresDist1</id>
  <value>1.2</value>
  <tag />
  <visible>false</visible>
  <history>|09/28/2017 3:08:14 AM||</history>
  <description />
  <comment />
</field>
<field>
  <id>txtAcresDist1Total</id>
  <value>200</value>
  <tag />
  <visible>false</visible>
  <history>|09/28/2017 3:08:14 AM||</history>
  <description />
  <comment />
</field>
</f1152_F1>
```

Comment: This is not possible using a simple `.modify()` to replace a value. Please provide an example of your XML, best was a working (reduced!) MCVE. This *might* be possible, but depends on the structure.

Comment: Appreciate your response. I have added the sample xml in the question section. I thought of using single updates and put it in stored procedure and run but thought it won't be that efficient.thanks